Unprotect on sheet even after saving
Please help I have 2 sheets out of 10 that keep protecting. I want them unprotected completely and never protected. My code is as follows NB: the two sheets are Recon 2103 & Recon 2123:
Private Sub quickProt()

For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Sheet.Name = "Master" Or Sheet.Name = "GL" Or Left(Sheet.Name, 2) = "BE" Or Sheet.Name = "Log" Or Sheet.Name = "ZAA110" Or Sheet.Name = "Recon 2103" Or Sheet.Name = "Recon 2123" Then
        Sheet.Unprotect ("SSDPWD@123")
        'Sheet.Protect ("SSDPWD@123")
    Else
        Sheet.Protect ("SSDPWD@123")
    End If
Next Sheet

End Sub

As shown above, I added the two sheets on the list to unprotect.

A side note, there shouldn't be any parentheses around "SSDPWD@123". As to your main question, double check if the sheet names have trailing spaces.

Do you have any other code the changes the protection state?

@BigBen there is a space between "Recon" & numbers. I accounted for it in the code

@NickSlash let me check

"Trailing space" would refer to a space at the very end. In any case, likely the sheet name isn't what you think it is.

Add Debug.Print Sheet.Name, Len(Sheet.Name), (Sheet.Name = "Recon 2103") after For Each, it's helpful to validate sheets' name.

@BigBen Oh!! got you. Double checked nothing.

@NickSlash No other date code

@taller let me try that

@taller Template_EOD   12           False
Template_EOD   12           False

Is it all output in Immediate window?
